# Is there a javascript or web development library equivalent of ios' auto layout constraints concept?

Tags: javascript, ios, autolayout, constraints

Has anyone seen this done outside of ios development?

The auto layout constraint concept is very interesting and could be helpful in responsive web design, possibly?

What do you think/any equivalents out there?

Comment: You should explain what this auto layout thing is and how it differs from a responsive css. I had a quick look and it seems to do what almost any modern css library does. For example, you can see some demo with bootstrap here: http://expo.getbootstrap.com/

Comment: Auto layout constraints set constraints and will adhere to them at all screen sizes. I guess css styling can do do this in a way, I just was thinking of it differently.

Comment: Ok so a responsive css library should do the trick, have a look at bootstrap's documentation, it's easy to try and experiment with. It uses a grid system to fit your page in most of available screen sizes and definitions. It's a very supported library, you have a lot of free themes and plugins.

Comment: I meant more like a constraint system where you do not need to do breakpoints via media queries or breakpoints at all?

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is, it's called AutoLayout.js

https://github.com/IjzerenHein/autolayout.js

Comment: Hey it was really awesome. But can I use with traditional HTML element or with any custom web component? how can I integrate to use for responsive design?

Answer (score 1):

Its called AutolayoutJS. [Here read my blog post](https://nodejsethan.wordpress.com/2016/10/14/autolayout-js/) .This is a combination of material from varied resources.